# Render isometric TMXTilemap with antialiasing method

Tags: isometric, cocos2d-x, antialiasing

I'm currently working on a cocos2d-x project that uses isometric tile maps.all the tiles are as small as 64*64 px.So I have to scale the map up a little bit.TMXTilemap is handy but its render method scales each tile first and then draw them together,which will cause black gaps between tiles if you are using "anti-aliasing" for the map's texure.So I was thinking to render the whole map on a texture first,so that scaling it up with anti-aliasing method will look nice.I wonder how exactly I can do this.